# VS Code cursor in wrong position after tab

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

When I write some code, and then click Tab to autofill from context menu the cursor is now in the wrong position. It should be before ";" but for some reason it is after  ";". Worked fine for about a year, and now suddenly something like this, any ideas?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue.  I tried all of the solution proposals and searched snippets for it but can't found anything.
I was already using the **html css support** extension by ecmel. I deleted and reinstalled it, Closed the vscode program and open it again but I couldn't get any results. Finally **downgraded** vscode to **1.64** version from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64) and now cursor works like a charm. I wanted to write this answer for friends like me who did not get any results.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is related to snippets in vscode.

The easiest way to solve this is to use the snippet extension.

Install "**HTML CSS Support**" extension made by "**ecmel**" to visual studio code. Close the program and open it again and you are ready. Problem fixed.

Extension URL: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css

Long way:
You can write your own or update snippets, to solve this.

Documentation to make your own snippets: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets